# How to go to the merge menu if I already close it once in intellij idea?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, merge

I use idea git integration to use git.
I merged my brabch into develop branch and I saw a lot of conflicts. I cloased the merge window and Now I see following file content:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
            //For unregistered users with unfilled email
            if (userService.findUserByEmail(newEmail) != null) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(
                        msgSource.getMessage("RegistController.USER_EXISTS", null, LOCALE_RU),
                        HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
            }
            Long userId = (Long) session.getAttribute(USER_ID);
            user = userService.findUserById(userId);
=======
            TerminalUser user = null;
            Long userId = (Long) session.getAttribute(USER_ID);
            if (userId == null) {
                user = userService.createEmptyUser();
                session.setAttribute(USER_ID, user.getUserId());
            }else {
                 user = userService.findUserById(userId);
            }
>>>>>>> remotes/origin/wrike1234567890
```

And idea signs that merge is not completed:

[image]

How to return to the merge menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate a file with conflicts in the Changes tool window. (If it is already open in the editor use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> and select Changes)

Right click on the file in the Changes tool window and select the menu `Git > Resolve conflicts...` (This menu item is not available on files without conflicts, so it might be called a little differently because I don't see it right now).

Comment: Yes, it is working. please also advise how to make "abort merge" ?